For our postgres bulk update plan, why are subsequent updates of same rows faster?
We have a projects table with 18 million records. We're looking to update one partner_id column for all projects. We noticed updating the same rows a second time is much faster than the first update. The first time updating a batch of projects would was 1,200 projects a second. Then updating the same projects again was 4,000 projects a second.
Our goal is to reduce the time it takes to update this partner_id column. So we're thinking we could prep the batch of projects first by updating the rows with existing data just to group the records together in the table. Then update the partner_id column at the faster rate. Is it faster because the rows are closer together or something?
We also realized we can take advantage of HOT updates. So we're thinking:

Drop projects partner_id indexes and foreign key constraint. We'll validate dropping this index will be okay.
Temporarily setting a lower fill factor. Unsure exactly how low this should be. Does it need to be less than 50 if we want to update every row again? Especially if there's other unrelated traffic? Was thinking of going pretty low as it's a temp change and I don't want our updates to time out from not being able to do HOT updates.
Update the created_at column with its existing value. This moves relevant project rows in table together and these will also use the new fill factor right?
Update last six months of tenant projects in parallel. In a production fork, we've been able to update 350k or so in like 3 seconds with HOT updates.
Recreate indexes, foreign key constraint, and raise fill factor

